# Unable to install libgtk2.0-dev - Issue with sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, update-manager

I am using the following OS version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following message:

```
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                      
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                                                                        
Ign:1 https://dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                       
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                         
Get:6 https://dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian stable Release [3,674 B]                                                
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                            
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                    
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                             
Hit:11 https://release.memsql.com/production/debian memsql InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                           
Hit:4 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                               
Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [652 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages [580 kB]
Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages                     
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages [580 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages [580 kB]     
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages [580 kB]     
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages [580 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages [580 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages [580 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages [580 kB]     
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages [580 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages [580 kB]
Ign:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages       
Ign:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages                  
Ign:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages                      
Err:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe arm64 Packages                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Ign:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages                  
Ign:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main arm64 Packages                             
Ign:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages                      
Ign:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages  
Ign:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages                          
Ign:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages                     
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [1,012 kB]
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,060 kB]      
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en [328 kB]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [273 kB]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [204 kB]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [476 kB]
Err:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [892 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages [641 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages [641 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages [641 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages [641 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages [641 kB]
Ign:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Err:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Ign:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main arm64 Packages
Fetched 181 kB in 2s (89.4 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'etcher/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'https://deb.etcher.io stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

When I try to run the command to install gtk `sudo apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-dev` I get the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  autoconf automake autopoint debhelper dh-autoreconf dh-strip-nondeterminism gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 icu-devtools libarchive-cpio-perl libatk1.0-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev
  libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libgraphite2-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libice-dev libicu-dev
  libicu-le-hb-dev libicu-le-hb0 libiculx60 libmail-sendmail-perl libpango1.0-dev libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpixman-1-dev libpng-dev libpng-tools libpthread-stubs0-dev libsigsegv2
  libsm-dev libsys-hostname-long-perl libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev
  libxft-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev m4 pkg-config po-debconf x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  autoconf-archive gnu-standards autoconf-doc dh-make dwz libcairo2-doc libglib2.0-doc libgraphite2-utils libgtk2.0-doc libice-doc icu-doc libpango1.0-doc libsm-doc libxcb-doc libxext-doc m4-doc
  libmail-box-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  autoconf automake autopoint debhelper dh-autoreconf dh-strip-nondeterminism gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 icu-devtools libarchive-cpio-perl libatk1.0-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev
  libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libgraphite2-dev libgtk2.0-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libice-dev
  libicu-dev libicu-le-hb-dev libicu-le-hb0 libiculx60 libmail-sendmail-perl libpango1.0-dev libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpixman-1-dev libpng-dev libpng-tools libpthread-stubs0-dev
  libsigsegv2 libsm-dev libsys-hostname-long-perl libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev
  libxfixes-dev libxft-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev m4 pkg-config po-debconf x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-dev x11proto-fixes-dev
  x11proto-input-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev zlib1g-dev
0 upgraded, 73 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,487 kB/26.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 120 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 libglib2.0-dev-bin amd64 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 libglib2.0-dev amd64 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 libglib2.0-dev-bin amd64 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 libglib2.0-dev amd64 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib2.0/libglib2.0-dev-bin_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib2.0/libglib2.0-dev_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

For reference, this is my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file (I recently reset it to see if this is the issue)

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe main
```

Any idea what the issue may be. This is very frustrating.

Comment: Looks to me like your problem should be solved by the reset of your sources. Remember to run `sudo apt update` after changing your sources. Your original problem was a plain old mismatch between versions. Your system was trying to install a version that the mirror had superseded in the seconds/minutes/hours since your last `sudo apt update`. The usual solution is to take short break, get a sandwich, and then run `sudo apt update`, and then try the install again.

Comment: I was getting similar error on Debian, using `apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update` resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched in my synaptic package manager and i found that i have the version libgtk3.0 there. I have the same repositories than you(i use Lubuntu 18.04, but form another server) so i would suggest you install the 3.0 version(not dev, only 3.0) from the synapic package manager.

Try avoid use apt-get, i formatted the SO nearly 2 o 3 times this month because i installed things via terminal and after i cant remove correctly them.

If you need more help, feel free to ask.
Sorry is something dont sound well, im not english native :)

PD: you have libgtk3.0-dev too there. Try install it via synaptic

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your problem should be solved by the reset of your sources. 
Remember to run `sudo apt update` after changing your sources.

Your original problem was a plain old mismatch between versions. Your system was trying to install a version that the mirror had superseded in the seconds/minutes/hours since your last `sudo apt update`.

- You were trying to install `libglib2.0-dev`, version `2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4`
- The current version in the Ubuntu Repositories is `2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6`

The usual solution is to take short break, get a sandwich, then run `sudo apt update`, and then try the install again.